# How to extract a specific line strings using awk

Tags: awk

I need to extract from this line:

```
Susan Dalsass:(206) 654-6279:250:60:50 ----> (the line is in the susan.txt file)
```

only this strings:

```
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```

**using awk and regex pattern**. Maybe someone knows how to do it?

I tried to do something like this but it didn't work:

```
awk '/(Susan)[[:space:]](Dalsass).?([0-9]{3})[[:space:]]([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})/{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' susan.txt
```

Comment: Does the file contain only the one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the line(s) of interest are of the form `<name>:<phone>:<rest_of_line>`
- matching will be based solely on the `name` (first) field
- the full name (spelling and case) is known in advance otherwise we need to look at modifying the match logic to work on a) a substring and/or b) case sensitivity

Setup:

```
$ cat susan.txt
ignore this line
Susan Dalsass:(206) 654-6279:250:60:50
ignore this line
```

For this particular case there's really no need to use a (complicated?) regex when we can use some basic string matching capabilities of `awk` ...

Exact match on first field:

```
$ awk -F':' '$1=="Susan Dalsass" { print $1,$2 }' susan.txt
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```

Match on leading part of the input line:

```
$ awk -F':' '/^Susan Dalsass/ { print $1,$2 }' susan.txt
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```

Using a `bash` variable for an exact match on the name:

```
$ fullname="Susan Dalsass"
$ awk -v name="${fullname}" -F':' '$1==name { print $1,$2 }' susan.txt
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```

Using a `bash` variable to do a partial match on the name:

```
$ partname="Susan"
$ awk -v name="${partname}" -F':' '$1~name { print $1,$2 }' susan.txt
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```

Using a `bash` variable to do a partial, case-sensitive match on the name:

```
$ partname="saSS"
$ awk -v name="${partname}" -F':' 'tolower($1)~tolower(name) { print $1,$2 }' susan.txt
Susan Dalsass (206) 654-6279
```